# I've always vs I always

Tags: meaning

I knew it was you because you always knock first, and then enter.

I knew it was you because you've always knocked first, and then entered.

Is there a differnece?

Comment: Yeah, they're different.  Mean pretty much the same thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

When someone does something regularly use simple present. Don't make a big deal out of it

Comment: Actually I agree with your advice here, but it should be “someone does”. It might get deleted anyway as an opinion without backup.

Answer (score -1):

The first example "I knew it was you because you always knock first, and then enter", is more correct.

The second one "I knew it was you because you've always knocked first, and then entered', is grammatically OK, but may not be suitable to talk about one's nature.

Answer (score -1):

second one is not grammatically  correct because it Doesn't have perfect tense blending.   Simple past tense doesn’t match with present perfect.